# what is wrong with following inline assembly code?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

What is wrong with the following code?

```
__asm__("mov %0, %%eax" : :"a" (ptr));
__asm__(".intel_syntax noprefix");//switch to intel syntax.
asm("lidt [eax]");
```

I get error in compilation like this:

`/tmp/cciOoSro.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cciOoSro.s:1737: Error: no such instruction: popl %ebp`

This is to load interrupt descriptor table IDT for my Os. But seems something wrong. I am not used to at&t syntax. I am used to intel syntax.

the function is to load the pointer of my idt to the processor using lidt.

```
void setup_idt(uint32 ptr) //to setup the idt i.e to load the idt's pointer
{
   __asm__("mov %0, %%eax" : :"a" (ptr));
   __asm__(".intel_syntax noprefix");//switch to intel sytax.     
   __asm__("lidt [eax]");
}
```

Comment: Could you supply a little more context? Maybe the whole function containing the asm?

Comment: Why not just `__asm__("lidt %0" :: "q"(ptr));` instead (if I understand correctly what you try to do)? It seems weird to have an "a" constraint (which puts `ptr` into EAX) only to move the contents to EAX and then having EAX hardcoded in the following instruction. The purpose of that ugly extended syntax is to already put values into the register you want and being flexible in the assembly code.

Comment: Another problem is you can't just write to a register without telling the compiler. You need to tell it you clobbered `eax` or bad things will happen.

Comment: i tried it like:  __asm__("mov %0, %%eax" : :"a" (ptr) : %%eax);   But it gave an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `.intel_syntax noprefix` line applied to everything until the end of the source. So it tried to interpreted gcc's assembly code as Intel code.

You should:
1. Merge all assembly line into one `__asm__` statement (`__asm__("line one\n" "line two\n")`.
2. The last line should do `.att_syntax prefix`, to return to AT&T syntax.

Or just use AT&T syntax. It isn't so hard.

Comment: He could also have a look here http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly/Examples#LIDT